# How to consume messages in RabbitMQ one by one in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

By default, the consume() function consumes all the messages that are in the queue, but I need pop only one message from the queue, and with the next consume() call pop the second message from the queue, etc. I have this code:

**rabbit.js** (in this file I have implemented the sending to and receiving from the queue):

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

var ch;

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, channel) {     
    ch = channel;
  });
});

module.exports.queueSend = function(msg) {
    var q = 'hello';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});

    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg));
    console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
}

module.exports.queueReceive = function() {
    var q = 'hello';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});

    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);

    ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
      console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
    }, {noAck: false});
}
```

**rabbit_test.js** (in this file I have tested the functionality of the previous code):

```
var rabbit = require("./rabbit");

setTimeout(function() {
    rabbit.queueSend("01C");
    rabbit.queueSend("02C");
    rabbit.queueReceive();
}, 2000);
```

When I call the `queueReceive()` function, it prints out the "01C" and "02C" messages too, not only the "01C". I need print out only the "01C" and with a next `queueReceive()` call the "02C".

P.S.: I tried this code too in **rabbit.js** for function `queueReceive()`:

```
module.exports.queueReceive = function() {
    var q = 'hello';

    ch.prefetch(1);
    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});

    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);

    ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
      ch.ack(msg);
      console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
    }, {noAck: false});
}
```

I added the `ch.ack(msg)` and `ch.prefetch(1)` parts, but it doesn't works neither.

How can i get this working? Thank you!